# Как сделать отступы между input-ами?

Tags: java, html, css, веб-программирование, itemtouchhelper

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать отступы между инпутами? Пробовал все свойства margin и padding. Не помогает

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  height: 60px;
}

.header-logo {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #A1A1A1;
  font-weight: 800;
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 12%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

nav {
  margin-top: 56px;
  margin-left: 23%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.topnav a {
  margin-top: 20px;
  color: #A1A1A1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.topnav .icon {
  display: none;
}

.pod-header {
  height: 600px;
  background: #719DCA;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.leader-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.pod-leader-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.center-wrapper {
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.forms {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
}

input {
  outline: none;
  padding: 13px;
  width: 250px;
}

button {
  outline: none;
  background: #FFBA41;
  padding: 13px;
  width: 250px;
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: bold;
}

i.fas {
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin-top: 9px;
  margin-right: -40px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #858585;
}

i.fas+input {
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>Maket</title>
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/b99ef0a656.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="header-logo">
      <p> LOGO </p>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
        <a href=""> HOME </a>
        <a href=""> SERVICE </a>
        <a href=""> ABOUT US </a>
        <a href=""> PROCING TABLE </a>
        <a href=""> HOW IT WORK </a>
        <a href=""> HAPPY CLIENTS </a>
        <a href=""> CONTACT US </a>
        <a href="" class="icon" id="menu"> &#9776; </a>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="pod-header">
    <div class="center-wrapper">
      <div class="leader-texts">
        <div class="leader-text"> BOOST UP YOUR LOCAL BUSINESS </div>
        <div class="pod-leader-text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam necessitatibus eaque itaque aliquam aliquid, sunt. </div>
      </div>
      <div class="forms">
        <i class="fas fa-user-edit"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Full Name">
        <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email Address">
        <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Phone Number">
        <button class="button-pod-header"> Request </button>
      </div>
  </section>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Это должно работать. А они у тебя в списке находятся? Если да, можно попробовать это:

```
li {
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```